# Can nagios check_mk be used to send the contents of a text file to a group of users and if so, how?

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I have a server that copies files between two ftp sites, a middleman server because the sites have been locked down to only accent connection to this server.

Ocassionally the process stops sending files but then executable itself does not crash, it just does not process anymore.

The text file is a log file which shows the files copied during the day.